# Importing ASTER Data into ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, arcgis-10.4, raster-conversion, aster

I have recently downloaded ASTER data from the glovis.usgs.gov website. The data was downloaded in a .HDF format and I have been unable to open these files in Arcmap, i'm using ArcGIS 10.4. When trying to add the file to ArcMap I receive a warning stating "Invalid raster dataset. Failed to create raster layer".

Can someone help me remedy this problem or point me in another direction to get free ASTER imagery?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try http://gdex.cr.usgs.gov/gdex/ where you can download geotiffs, as written here: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/node/1079
I used that source for an arcgis project too.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can use this tool, http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/extract-subdataset.htm, and that should do it. Just remember to set reprojection to where you want them to be...

I have had done that worked with ASTER and they were in HDF format.

Comment: I have tried using the extract-subdataset tool before but the problem with that is that it gives me the options of over a thousand subdatasets to choose from. Once I select the subdatasets it asks whether i want to draw the pyramids but then that tool fails and then it fails to  draw the raster.

Comment: Do you have ERDAS or ENVI ?

Comment: I do not.. My graduate university doesn't have the license for it and i'm trying to avoid buying the license with my grant money.